# How to remove default styling of html 5 form elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I reset or change the default styling of the email input element?

```css
input
{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="text box" /><br /><br />
<input type="email" placeholder="email box with default styling when invalid email is entered" />
```

I want the validation of email element to remain as it is. Just want to change the red border when wrong email is entered.

Comment: Provide us some more code and please be clear.

Comment: The question does not asks what you describe as your actual needs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not particularly clear what you are after, however note that you can style the invalid state of **HTML5** (you must be using a compatible browser) input fields using the `:invalid` pseudo.

```css
input:invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="enter some letters.." />
```

If however you are referring to removing default input styling, you will either have to override the useragent stylesheet defaults, or depending on the styles in question use (a derivation of) [**`appearance:none`**](http://caniuse.com/#search=appearance)

> The appearance property defines how elements (particularly form
>   controls) appear by default.

Comment: yeah I was looking for something like you said about the pseudo element - :invalid.
I want to know its browser support.. Is it supported in major browsers??

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to check in the validation

```
var email = document.querySelector('input[type="email"]');
email.oninvalid = function(e) {
e.target.setCustomValidity("");
if (!e.target.validity.valid) { 
    email.style.borderColor="red";
    e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter a valid eMail address"); }
};
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/uKZGp/217/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to handle html5's built in behavior for validation. This seems to be what you are looking for, pseudoclasses like :invalid. More info here: http://html5doctor.com/css3-pseudo-classes-and-html5-forms/

The solution will not be all that cross-browser. I recommend using js for client side validation, something like jquery validate: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score -1):

You can add a "class" to email input when it's wrong, for example:

```
input[type="email"].error {
    border-color: red;
}
```

Is that what you was looking for?